# Android - Frame layout height not matching with coordinator layout

Tags: android, height, matching, android-framelayout

I have a problem with my FrameLayout (Container in Drawer Layout). The height of the FrameLayout exceeds the screen height (below the android default menu buttons at bottom).

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/navContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: Height exceeding as seen in Android Studio Designer]

Comment: I am getting same problem , Is this android Coordinator bug or is their any workaround for this. (Without giving the margin bottom as dimen of action bar height)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My first attempt was to set a `android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"` at the FrameLayout. This solved the solution for non-scrollable views having a "fixed" height in terms of no vertically scrollable content (like a usual RelativeLayout with `match_parent` height). Aligning a component to the parent bottom (`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`) results in a still visible element. In Android Studio's Previewer the no exceeding of the height is visible.

However, this marginBotton-fix introduces a new problem for fragments whose root view is scrollable (like a RecyclerView). For these views when scrolling down the bottom margin will become visible in a white bar (in case white is the background color). This seams reasonable, as for those views the nested scrolling feature will slide out the toolbar
[image: ListView with last item cut]

**tl;dr** I worked around that issue by applying the the `?attr/actionBarSize` as bottom margin to non-scrollable fragments that are shown inside the Framelayout. Prior to that I set the height of the toolbar to be `?attr/actionBarSize`.

Activity layout:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/navContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
          android:orientation="vertical">
          <!-- Further stuff here -->
          <TextView android:id="@+id/label"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          />
  </LinearLayout>
```

The only downside I faced right now is the white space to be shown in Android Studio's Previewer while creating the fragment layout.

Comment: This worked nicely for me! As a side-note, If one of your fragments has a scrollable root which hides the app bar, it will remain hidden when navigating back to a previous (non-scrollable) fragment with no way to show it again. There is a workaround for this issue [available here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30554824/1794631).

Answer (score 2):

If you use different `Fragments` inside your `CoordinatorLayout` you will face the problem, that some `Fragments` have scrollable content and some should not scroll. Your `Toolbar` has the scrolling flags "`scroll|enterAlways`", which is ok for the former layouts, but not ok for the latter. My solution is a custom `AppBarLayout.Behavior` which switches the scrolling flags dependant on the custom tag (contentShouldNotScrollTag). Set this tag for the layouts, which should not scroll like this:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:tag="@string/contentShouldNotScrollTag">
   <!-- my non-scrollable Fragment layout -->
</FrameLayout>
```

As the result, the height of this Fragment will not exceed the screen's height. Here is the custom behavior class for the `AppBarLayout`:

```
public class MyScrollBehavior extends AppBarLayout.Behavior {
    private View content;

    public MyScrollBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout parent, AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int parentWidthMeasureSpec, int widthUsed, int parentHeightMeasureSpec, int heightUsed) {
        if(content == null) {
            content = parent.findViewById(R.id.container);
        }

        if(content != null) {
            boolean shouldNotScroll = content.findViewWithTag(parent.getContext().getString(R.string.contentShouldNotScrollTag)) != null;
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) appBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params =
                    (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
            if (shouldNotScroll) {
                params.setScrollFlags(0);
                appBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);
            } else {
                params.setScrollFlags(AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_SCROLL
                        | AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.SCROLL_FLAG_ENTER_ALWAYS);
            }
        }

        return super.onMeasureChild(parent, appBarLayout, parentWidthMeasureSpec, widthUsed, parentHeightMeasureSpec, heightUsed);
    }
}
```