# ViewPager and other viewGroup in CoordinatorLayout not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-toolbar, android-design-library

I observed that adding **appbar_scrolling_view_behavior** to a **ViewPager** and that viewPager is not fullScreen (in my case contains some bottom buttons/tabs), **then the viewPager has a bigger height (with the height of the toolbar I guess)** and overlaps with the other layout(in my case those tabs)

See the images below (one is with the toolbar scrolled up)
[image: See how the recyclerView from the viewPager is BELOW the tabs]

[image: Now the toolbar is scrolled up and the viewPager is OK now]

This is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".AudioRecActivity"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottomLayout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/acb_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <audiorec.com.gui.views.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/secondary" >
    </audiorec.com.gui.views.SlidingTabLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/adsContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/secondary" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/loading_ad_tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/advertisement_loading"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**How the ViewPager/CoordinatorLayout content can be under that Linearlayout if I specified not to be?**

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777698/android-footer-scrolls-off-screen-when-used-in-coordinatorlayout/31140112#31140112) and works for me as well

It appears it is a "problem" from android team....see here: [issue on android](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177195)