# Fix bottom bar in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I have a `CoordinatorLayout` which contains `AppBarLayout` and a `FrameLayout` which contains fragments.

One of this fragment contains a `TabLayout` at Top, one List trough `RecyclerView` and at the Bottom one "homemade" toolbar.

The `AppBarLayout` is configured with `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"`

My problem is that both "toolbars" are hiding when scroll, the AppBarLayout and my "homemade" toolbar at the bottom. This is the current behaviour

[image]

I would like to fix the bottom "homemade" toolbar to keep visible but I can't achieve it.

This is the XML of the fragment Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarfilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/azul_asde"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/verde_pastel"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarselection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@color/azul_asde"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp"
            android:tint="@color/gris_desactivado" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/select"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bookmark_border_white_24dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_white_24dp"
            android:tint="@color/gris_desactivado" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT1:** [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777698/android-footer-scrolls-off-screen-when-used-in-coordinatorlayout/33396965#33396965)  questions seems to be the same problem.

Comment: Could you do me a favor and show us how you are hiding the bottom bar? I can't seem to figure it out ... (I don't need the top bar, just the bottom)

Comment: Hi Hanzo,

Did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: can you post your xml file that contains `CoordinatorLayout`

Comment: Your bottom bar needs to be at the CoordinatorLayout level with a bottom gravity, else it will scroll with the rest of the content.

Comment: can't you just implement your fragment layout using a RecyclerView?

Comment: hey give me code please i need this

Comment: i need This  behaviour please help me ?

Comment: i  remove weight from SwipeRefreshLayout .

Answer (score 9):

Try this layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Test" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Test" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Test" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Test" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/card_view5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:layout_height="110dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="Test" />

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/green"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/bottomnav"
            app:menu="@menu/main">


        </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

    </RelativeLayout>



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: For future readers, RelativeLayout is heavily discouraged in modern Android apps

Comment: You know, CoordinatorLayout does not allow child to use `gravity` so it will not work

Answer (score 9):

The best possible solution will be making this kind of hierarchy

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <CoordinatorLayout>
        <AppBarLayout>
           <ToolBar>
           <TabLayout>
        </AppBarLayout>
        <Inlude>
           Put the Main Content here.
        </Include>
    </CoordinatorLayout>

 
   Other Widgets that you want to be placed at a fixed position.

</ConstraintLayout>
```

Don't forget to add

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

the above line into your included layout parent ViewGroup

Let's have an example of the approach that I am talking about

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/container"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:context=".activity.Dashboard">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/container"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/background"
                android:elevation="0dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:titleTextColor="#000000" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabBackground="@color/background"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/black" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/content_main" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/container"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btReceive">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fbSend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_upload"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/fbSend"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/fbSend"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/fbSend"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="SEND"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8sdp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btReceive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_50sdp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/container"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btSend"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fbReceive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_download"
            app:rippleColor="@color/colorAccent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/fbReceive"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/fbReceive"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/fbReceive"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_3sdp"
            android:elevation="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="RECEIVE"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_8sdp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_7sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar_corner"
        android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_upload_download"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/_6sdp"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_6sdp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

So far so good. Let's have a look at the result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can try and add the collapseMode on your toolbar something like this.

Your appBarLayout seems fine

I would advise u to look at this link: [Handling Scrolls with CoordinatorLayout](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout)

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
          app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/profile_tablayout_indicator_height"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/red"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
                    android:textColor="#ffFFff" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
                    android:textColor="#ffFFff" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/red"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
                    android:textColor="#ffFFff" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
                    android:textColor="#ffFFff" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/red"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
                    android:textColor="#ffFFff" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
                    android:textColor="#ffFFff" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/red"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
                    android:textColor="#ffFFff" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
                    android:textColor="#ffFFff" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/red"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
                    android:textColor="#ffFFff" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
                    android:textColor="#ffFFff" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/red"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
                    android:textColor="#ffFFff" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Nilesh Rathod"
                    android:textColor="#ffFFff" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomnav"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:foregroundGravity="bottom"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/lightWhite"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/lightWhite"
            app:menu="@menu/menu"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: BottomNavigationView overlaps ScrollView. Expectable margin needed.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior basically removes scroll flag `SCROLL` from `AppBarLayout`, when scrolling content in dependent view (`RecyclerView`, `NestedScrollView`) is less than view height, ie. when scrolling is not needed. It also overrides offsetting scrolling view, which is normally done by `AppBarLayout.ScrollingViewBehavior`. Works well when adding footer, ie. button, to scrolling view or in `ViewPager`, where content length may be different in each page.

https://gist.github.com/MaciejKaras/02bff315f00b87d80467a470424f22c3

Answered already in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37293634

Answer (score 1):

To fix Bottom bar, firstly you have to use a Activity where tabs present. In that activity use different fragments. Add your tabLayout in this activity_main_tab.xml

activity_main_tab.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/co_activity_root_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                local:theme="@style/Theme.AppBarOverlay"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_layout">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fl_fragment_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For fragment view use

fragment_tab.xml

here use app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" in toolbar to make it scrollable

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tablayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="@dimen/profile_tablayout_indicator_height"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:tabGravity="fill"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

FragmentTabs.java

```
 public class FragmentTabs extends BaseFragment{

        private View rootView;
        private ViewPager viewPager;
        private TabLayout tabLayout;
        private Toolbar toolbar;
        private ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroupContainer, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            rootViewSearch = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab, viewGroupContainer, false);
            initializeLayout();
            setUpActionBar();
            setUpFragmentObjects();

            return rootView;
        }


        private void initializeLayout() {
            toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            tabLayout = (TabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        }


        private void setUpActionBar() {
            getApplicationContext().setSupportActionBar(toolbarSearch);
            ActionBar actionBar = getApplicationContext().getSupportActionBar();
            if(actionBar != null){
                actionBar.setTitle(Constants.BLANK);
            }
        }


        private void setUpFragmentObjects() {
            viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), getChildFragmentManager());
            viewPager.setAdapter(searchViewPagerAdapter);
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    }
```

ViewPagerAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity activity, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Bundle bundle;
        switch (position) {
            case 0: // For Tab 1
               // use fragment for tab 1
                return fragment1;
            case 1: // For Tab 2
                // use fragment for tab 2
                return fragment2;
            case 2: // For Tab 3
                // use fragment for tab 3
                return fragment3;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3; // no. of Tabs
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: // Title For Tab1
                return "Tab1";
            case 1: // Title For Tab2
                return "Tab2";
            case 2: // Title For Tab3
                return "Tab3";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced same problem Here is the way That worked for me

Remove the `AppBarLayout` `layout_behavior` so it fixed on top. Define the `FrameLayout` layout_behavior as `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` so it adjust `FrameLayout` below the `AppBarLayout`. In this way way your content of frame layout will scroll but not toolbar. `CoordinatorLayout` layout like as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.next_tech.teebox.GridView">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


</FrameLayout>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the XML of the your fragment Layout where your `recyclerView` scroll without affecting your `TabLayout` and bottom Linear Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarfilter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/btnBackground"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
        />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarselection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/select"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/white_arrow" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send_holo_dark" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I hope it helps someone thanks

for more info -
[Scrolling Behavior for Appbars in Android](https://android.jlelse.eu/scrolling-behavior-for-appbars-in-android-41aff9c5c468#.gwtgih9na)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in coordinatorlayout. so use RelativeLayout and within its design your own layout

Answer (score 0):

2021 Update:
Fixing BottomNavBar, with Toolbar hiding when scrolling.

In activity_main.xml
We have 3 things -

1. Toolbar
2. FragmentContainerView
3. BottomNavigationView

Building on Rishabh Dhiman's solution
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64896704/15392387

```
<ConstraintLayout>
    <CoordinatorLayout>
        <AppBarLayout>
           <ToolBar>
        </AppBarLayout>
        <FragmentContainerView>
    </CoordinatorLayout>
    <BottomNavigationView>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is an example, which works for me -

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"

            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />


    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Note: This works well if Fragment in the FragmentContainerView is scrollable. Otherwise, the bottom of the fragment gets hidden behind the BottomNavigationView.

Comment: Not working for me. BottomNavigationView overlap content in FragmentContainerView and when I go to next pages, toolbar push content to bottom make them dissapear

Comment: @Patrick - To fix the overlapping content issue, make changes to CoordinatorLayout. Set height and width to match constraints and add -app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView". Let me know if it works (y)

Comment: Nothing... I've been trying for 3 days to have a bottomnavigationview with a custom toolbar that can be hidden and I can't do it. Always overlaps above or below

Comment: can you share your code? Would be able to help better...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69513412/bottomnavigationview-overlap

With your solution the bottomnavigationview overlaps my view. Moreover, if in a later fragment I put a button with 20 margin with respect to bottom, it is covered with the bottomnavigationview and when I hide the toolbar, there it is shown because the button goes up