# Youtube like scrolling behaviour

Tags: java, android, scroll, android-recyclerview, toolbar

I have `Frame Layout(Each Containing RecyclerView)`, `Bottom Navigation Bar` and a `Custom toolbar`.

I want that for each `Fragment` whenever their is some upward scrolling event occurs, my `toolbar` should hide and whenever comes back whenever down scrolling event occurs.

Can you help to do this as I am new to Android Programming.

Comment: You could use a `CoordinatorLayout` and manage the collapsing modes.

Comment: Can you help me with that more.But I have recyceler view in Fragment and RecyclerView in Fragment

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing source code enables members to offer more specific advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576290/fix-bottom-bar-in-coordinatorlayout) or [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777698/android-footer-scrolls-off-screen-when-used-in-coordinatorlayout).

These questions answer the problem of hiding the bottom bar.

Comment: These doesn't explain how to implement it. I want to know how can I implement this in my app.