# How to fix footer properly which is inside CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android

I tend to further elaborate from this

[Android - footer scrolls off screen when used in CoordinatorLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777698/android-footer-scrolls-off-screen-when-used-in-coordinatorlayout)

and

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=177195

*I wish to hide `TabLayout` while performing scrolling on `RecyclerView`*. That's why I have the following layout.

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        <TabLayout>
    <ViewPager>
        <RecyclerView>
        <Footer>
```

For my situation, I have a `ViewPager` which contains multiple fragments.

Most of the fragments, contains `RecyclerView` and footer. They look like the following

```
<LinearLayout>
    <RecyclerView />
    <LinearLayout id="@+id/footer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Unfortunately, the footer is movable when scrolling, although I would like it to be static.

Note, it is important to have `app:layout_behavior` to place in `ViewPager` instead of `RecyclerView`. If not, `TabLayout` will not appear.

My implementation is as follow

### my_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="?attr/portfolioTabIndicatorColor" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="org.yccheok.xxx.CustomScrollingViewBehavior"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The very key class is `org.yccheok.xxx.CustomScrollingViewBehavior`, which is copied and pasted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/33396965/72437

`org.yccheok.xxx.CustomScrollingViewBehavior` is the best solution I can find so far. However, it is far from perfect, as it yields the following behavior.

It causes flickering, when you scroll up a little, and release your finger. Please refer to the following video.

https://youtu.be/8RvCZJeQvS0

*I was wondering, based on proposed solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33396965/72437, is there any further improvement I can done on `CustomScrollingViewBehavior` class, to avoid flickering effect?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to achieve what I want, by following tutorial at

https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling%28part1%29/

http://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/28/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part2%29/

The key ideas are

1. Don't use `CoordinatorLayout`
2. Place `TabLayout` and `RecyclerView` within `FrameLayout`, so that `TabLayout` will overlay on the top of `RecyclerView`
3. Add top padding on `RecyclerView`. Having `android:clipToPadding="false"` is important as well.
4. To hide/ show `TabLayout` during scrolling, attach [HidingScrollListener](https://github.com/mzgreen/HideOnScrollExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/pl/michalz/hideonscrollexample/listener/parttwo/HidingScrollListener.java) to `RecyclerView`.

The shortcoming for this solution is that, `requiresFadingEdge` will no longer work on `RecyclerView`, due to the top padding.