# footer scrolls off screen when used in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have HomeActivity which contains fragment and at the bottom it has custom navigation view as shown below.

[image]

By clicking on profile pic, it replaces the fragment with UserProfileView fragment. userProfileView fragment has Collapsing toolbar inside coordinatorLayout.

userprofileview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="resource"
            type="com.example.app.model.ResourceData" />


        <import type="android.view.View" />

    </data>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/bg_home"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/bg_home">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ic_list"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_17sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_17sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_list_selected" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ic_grid_view"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_15sdp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_grid_unselected" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/rv_post"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:resource="@{resource}" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

The problem is when i click to any other menu from bottom navigation menu, it scrolls off the screen as shown below.

[image]

This issue is occurring after adding CoordinatorLayout in UserProfileView framgment.

If i replace CoordinatorLayout with LinearLayout then it works fine but doesn't get the functionality of collapsing toolbar.

Thank you!

Comment: I think the scenario you are describing here is similar to [the issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777698/android-footer-scrolls-off-screen-when-used-in-coordinatorlayout) so I suggest trying to implement one of the recent solutions there

Comment: @NoaDrach I've tried that and also commented my question over there. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post a simple project with that behavior at github?

Comment: Yeah sure. https://github.com/chetanparmar95/TestApp.
Also I've used "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" theme but if I use DarkActionBar instead of NoActionBar then it works properly but ActionBar comes down the same way BottomView is moving

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in your `fragment_user_profile.xml` causes problem. Simply... it makes your drawer layout looks fullscreen.

Roughly, `user` screen maintains top indicator margin and `home` screen doesn't. So home screen moved up as indicator size. (Actually it isn't, Details about fitsSystemWindows:
[Why would I want to fitsSystemWindows](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec))

So, remove fitsSystemWindows from `fragment_user_profile.xml` will fix your problem.

And I suggest you add `fitsSystemWindows` to your `container_body` in `activity_main.xml`, but I'm not sure that what is the actual code, so it is your call.