# How to stop Bottom navigation bar overlapping recyclerview?

Tags: android, overlapping, android-bottomnav

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ymbrj.gif

How to stop Android Bottom navigation bar overlapping recyclerview ?
i need to solve problem but i have no idea. I've tried a lot of ways. In the end, I can not reach. I need your help.
I read the current topics. I think my problem is more comprehensive. The Recyler prints cardviews on the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"


    xmlns:design="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.hasan.simpleblog.MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#ffffff"

            >

            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/NavBot"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="#ffff"
                design:menu="@menu/menu_nav"

                >

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="4dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
            </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >

            </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/blog_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Image you provided is not from this layout.. am I right?

Comment: on the recyclerview remove the margin bottom

Comment: Yes, my layout is different.

Comment: Add your screenshots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ConstraintLayout. 
**Align the bottom edge of top view to the top edge of bottom view.**

Example

xml

```
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:divider="@color/black"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"></ListView>

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
      </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Design

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you use **CoordinatorLayout** (like above). You can customize your view behavior to do exact same thing.

Here are some greate posts:

[BignerdRanch Tutorial](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/customizing-coordinatorlayouts-behavior/)

[Ian Lake Introduce](https://medium.com/google-developers/intercepting-everything-with-coordinatorlayout-behaviors-8c6adc140c26)

Comment: I could not handle it

Comment: Like this issue. You can try one of answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30777698/android-footer-scrolls-off-screen-when-used-in-coordinatorlayout